# How to tab to next file when renaming?

Tags: nautilus, rename

If I am renaming a bunch of files in Nautilus quickly, when I hit Enter the file jumps to its proper place alphabetically. But that means I have to go back and find the next file I wanted to rename.

Is there any way to easily tab to the next file when renaming, like in Windows? I tried various keys but nothing works.

Note: I am *not looking for a batch renamer* like the `rename` command, I am renaming a handful of files with no pattern to them.

Comment: You can group it by size because renaming will not affect size.

Comment: @totti True, but I still have to press Enter then an arrow key then F2 to go to the next one. Plus I was trying to rename some files that started with numbers so I had to have them in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible with Nautilus right now, everything gets reordered every time you make a change. So, your only option is doing like totti says: choosing another kind of ordering so file order doesn't change if you rename a file.

That concerns Nautilus, though. Perhaps other file managers, like Dolphin or Thunar, allow the kind of behaviour you want, but I seriously doubt it...